# Error commit, and push in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to add a IOS project to bitbucket,
So I did this:

```
cd /path/to/my/project
git init
git remote add origin https://nunito@bitbucket.org/nunito/my_first_app_ios.git

acBook-Pro-de-nunito:MyFirstApp nunito$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
    MyFirstApp.xcodeproj/
    MyFirstApp/
    MyFirstAppTests copy-Info.plist
    MyFirstAppTests/
    icons/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

But the while project has not been added to git !!!!

Comment: You need to run `git add` before committing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add files before commit!

For example, you add a file or a directory like this:

```
git add filename
```

Then commit with message:

```
git commit -m "This is commit message to show what does the added file do"
```

Then run `git push -u origin master` to push to the origin repo's master branch, and set that the `origin master` branch as the upstream of your local master branch.

Pro-git is really a good book to learn git: https://git-scm.com/documentation